# Javascript loop wait until api call finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code ,

```
$.each(result, function (index, value) {
  if (value.name != null) {                       
    $.ajax({
      // myApi call code
    });
  }
  // I only want reach here after api call finish
  if (value.flag) {}
});
```

There are two condition inside loop , one is checking `name != null` and api call inside , the next is `value.flag` . I just want to reach to second condition after api call complete .

Comment: yes , please consider the `if` conditions also .

Answer (score 0):

you can use done function when ajax request completes

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
$.ajax({
  // options
})
  .done(function (response) {
    // do something with the response
  })
  .fail(function (response) {
    // handle the error case
  })
  .always(function (response) {
    // do something always at the end of the sequence
  })
```

With that in mind, you'll have to move the `value.flag` check to the callbacks:

```
$.each(result, function (index, value) {
  if (value.name != null) {
    $.ajax({ /* options */ })
      .done(function (response) {
        // this check will happen only if the request succeeds
        if (value.flag) {}
      })
      .fail(function (response) {
        // this check will happen only if the request fails
        if (value.flag) {}
      })
      .always(function (response) {
        // this check will always happen after the request
        if (value.flag) {}
      })
  }
)};
```

Comment: can you describe with my code ?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: according to your code , I think  if `value.name == null` , then the second condition `value.flag` cannot reach , am I right ?

Comment: @zey if value.name==null do you want to execute value.flag?

Comment: yes of course. you can check my code.

Comment: @zey, it'll be easier to address your questions if you add more detail to your question, as it's not clear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @zey: your question gives the impression that value.flag should execute only after api call "I just want to reach to second condition after api call complete .". Kindly rephrase your question

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want all Ajax calls **and** iterations completed after doing something, so I think you want something like this:

```
var i = result.length - 1;
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
      if (value.name != null) {
        $.ajax({
          //code
        }).done(function() {
          i--;//<-- subtract 1 if ajax is completed
        });
      } else {
        i--;//<-- subtract 1 if value.name == null
      }
      if (!i) {//<-- it's true only if all ajax are completed and all iterations are made
        if (value.flag) {}
      }

    }
```

Comment: according to your code , I think if `value.name == null` , then the second condition `value.flag` cannot reach , am I right ?

Comment: @zey Yes, but if value.name == null not all calls are made

Comment: please recheck my code ,even `value.name` is null or not , should reach  the second condition .

Comment: @zey I'm not sure if I understand, I've updated the answer, in that way we could only reach `if (value.flag) {}` if all requests and iterations are made. Am I right?